# 'Perspective' transformation with GDI+ in C#

Tags: c#, matrix, graphics, gdi+, rectangles

I would like to transform a picture with GDI+ in C#. I would like to do the two transformations in the picture shown, but I only find skew (shear) transformations, which is not really what I want to do. I'm looking for a 'perspective' like transformation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUBtV.jpg

Is it possible to do something similar with a Matrix, like shown in the crude picture?

Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest using something like [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) which is a C# wrapper for the OpenGL API.

Comment: No, only affine transforms are possible in GDI+.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I was looking for something simple, to avoid going 3D. I might be able to achieve something similar to what I had in mind with "predrawn" pictures in photoshop, and some skew.

Thanks for the help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix in GDI+ represents an affine matrix that results in affine [linear+shift] transformation. You need a bilinear transformation that uses x*y component and cannot be done by Matrix.

I was also wondering about such simple functionality and will report if I find something simple and directly applicable.